# How to Use Framer Motion for Transitions Between React Components with Swipe Gesture?

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I'm just starting to use REACT, and I want to make it so that to switch between pages (components), I can not only animate the transition but also slide with my finger.

In other words, it displays page1, I swipe to the left with my finger, and it loads and simultaneously displays the content of page2 on the side. I can navigate between both while keeping my finger pressed. When I release my finger, only one page remains loaded.

**In this example, I do it more or less with a button, I want it to work both with a button and while I swipe**

**I'm trying Framer Motion, but I'm not quite sure if I need swipe, drag... and how to apply it between components (ultimately, they will be routes).**

```
    // test.jsx
import { motion, AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion'
import { useState } from 'react'

import { Box } from './Box'

import { AnimeA } from '../framer/AnimeA'

export function Test() {

  const [value, setValue] = useState(1);
  const trans = value % 2 === 0 ? trans1 : trans2;

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ display: "flex", height: "116px" }}>

            <AnimeA keya={value}  transi={trans}>
                {<Box n={value}/>}
            </AnimeA>

      </div>
      <br/><br/>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => { setValue(value + 1); }}>
        Toggle
      </button>
    </>
    )
  }

  const trans1 = {
    style: { position: "relative", width: "100%", background: "red" },
    initial: { x: -100, opacity: 0 },
    animate: { x: 0, opacity: 1 },
    exit: { x: -100, opacity: 0, transition: { duration: 0.5 } },
    transition: {duration: 0.5 }
  }

  const trans2 = {
    style: { position: "relative", width: "100%", background: "blue" },
    initial:{ x: 100, opacity: 0 },
    animate:{ x: 0, opacity: 1 },
    exit:{ x: 100, opacity: 0, transition: { duration: 0.5 } },
    transition:{ duration: 0.5 }
  }


// AnimeA.jsx
import { motion } from 'framer-motion'
import {  AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion'

export function AnimeA({ keya, transi, children }) {
  return (
    <AnimatePresence initial={false} mode="popLayout">
        <motion.div key={keya} {...transi}>
            {children}
        </motion.div>
    </AnimatePresence>
  )
}
```

export default AnimeA

"The pages (box) shouldn't be loaded and hidden, the elements to be scrolled."

[image]

**"It is only loaded when the screen is first dragged to one side."**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution:-

use the `useGesture` hook provided by Framer Motion

```
import { motion, AnimatePresence, useGesture } from 'framer-motion'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { Box } from './Box'
import { AnimeA } from '../framer/AnimeA'

export function Test() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1)
  const trans = value % 2 === 0 ? trans1 : trans2
  const bind = useGesture({
    onDragEnd: (event, info) => {
      if (info.offset.x < -100) {
        setValue(value + 1)
      } else if (info.offset.x > 100) {
        setValue(value - 1)
      }
    },
  })

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', height: '116px' }}>
        <AnimeA keya={value} transi={trans} {...bind()}>
          {<Box n={value} />}
        </AnimeA>
      </div>
      <br/><br/>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => { setValue(value + 1); }}>
        Toggle
      </button>
    </>
  )
}

const trans1 = {
  style: { position: 'relative', width: '100%', background: 'red' },
  initial: { x: -100, opacity: 0 },
  animate: { x: 0, opacity: 1 },
  exit: { x: -100, opacity: 0, transition: { duration: 0.5 } },
  transition: { duration: 0.5 },
}

const trans2 = {
  style: { position: 'relative', width: '100%', background: 'blue' },
  initial: { x: 100, opacity: 0 },
  animate: { x: 0, opacity: 1 },
  exit: { x: 100, opacity: 0, transition: { duration: 0.5 } },
  transition: { duration: 0.5 },
}

// AnimeA.jsx
import { motion } from 'framer-motion'
import { AnimatePresence } from 'framer-motion'

export function AnimeA({ keya, transi, children }) {
  return (
    <AnimatePresence initial={false} mode="popLayout">
      <motion.div key={keya} {...transi}>
        {children}
      </motion.div>
    </AnimatePresence>
  )
}
```

Comment: useGesture doesn't exist in framer-motion, but if there is ondragend etc. although I have already tried that, I have the first component that is draggable and when I release it it is replaced by the second, but what I want is that while I drag the first component the second one appears attached to its side, for example Therefore it is an extra animation for ondrag, not only when releasing